# Cannot access child nodes while parsing XML with PHP and Xpath

Tags: php, xml, xpath, nodes

I have this following XML

```
<Logs>
  <UnplugDate>
    <Date>2013-09-10T09:20:00</Date>
    <Date>2013-09-09T16:03:00</Date>
  </UnplugDate>
```

What I'm trying to do here is to read the values of both  variables under `<UnplugDate`> tag.

I try to use the hasChildNodes() but when I debug It doesn't go inside

`foreach($unplug_date as $node)` 
block.

Any Idea how can I read these values? Thanks in advance

```
$logs    = $key->getElementsByTagName(tag_constants::TAG_LOGS);
$unplug_date = $logs->item(0)->getElementsByTagName(tag_constants::TAG_UNPLUG_DATE)->item(0);
foreach($unplug_date as $node) {
    if($node->hasChildNodes()) {
         foreach ($node->childNodes as $unplug_date_value) {
              $unplug_date_value = $unplug_date->getElementsByTagName(tag_constants::TAG_DATE)->item(0)->nodeValue;
         }
    }
}
```

NOTE:

```
tag_constants::TAG_LOGS        -> Logs
tag_constants::TAG_UNPLUG_DATE -> UnplugDate
tag_constants::TAG_DATE        -> Date
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've finally find the solution. Writing :

```
$test = $unplug_date->getElementsByTagName(tag_constants::TAG_DATE);
```

instead of

```
$unplug_date = $logs->item(0)->getElementsByTagName(tag_constants::TAG_UNPLUG_DATE)->item(0);
```

solves the problem.

Comment: But do you understand why? You were iterating over a DOMNode instead of DOMNodeList. I think using Xpath makes more sense here. You could evaluate this `string(//Logs/UnplugDate/Date)` to get that text

Comment: Yes, I understood that I was trying to get DOMNode. 
By the way I tried Xpath like
//UnplugDate[@Date] but didn't work. Going to check your string as well

Comment: That xpath didn't work because `@` denotes an attribute, you most likely meant: `//UnplugDate/Date`.

Comment: Oh I see now, I by using @ I'm trying to access an attribute which isn't even exists. Thanks guys for the tips